# Notify commenters about new replies

Tags: plugins, comments, email

Is there a plugin to notify commenters of one post to receive emails about new comments made on that post? Only commenters who entered emails will be notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this plugin out: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments/

Comment: Thanks, and I used this fork at the end. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/

Comment: can't configure "subscribe-to-comments-reloaded" properly and used "subscribe-to-comments-double-opt-in" instead

Answer (score 0):

you can use  a plugin called "comment reply notification"  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-reply-notification/

ps I didnt know anyone could add comments without leaving their email adress anyway as they could all be spammers then surely?

Comment: cool thanks, I tried the one above but can't make it to work yet. Think I'll give this a go.